# /dev/nvme0n1p1space is full how to clean it?

Tags: aws

I just set up my site through AWS EC2 not that long ago from following YouTube tutorial. Now I have issue with no space left on the disk space and I tried to remove some of the old backup files I have. However, when I ran `df -h` it was showing `/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  7.5G  232M  98% /`. I never ran into this kind of problem before and my site is still down. Is there a way to clean anything in `nvme0n1p1`? Thank you. (My site is very simple it just show some contents only nothing fancy)

```
➜  ~ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            470M     0  470M   0% /dev
tmpfs            97M  740K   96M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  7.5G  232M  98% /
tmpfs           481M     0  481M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           481M     0  481M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
tmpfs            97M     0   97M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop1       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10126
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10185
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop5       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2996



➜  ~ df -h /dev/nvme0n1p1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  7.5G  232M  98% /


➜  ~ sudo du -m / | sort -nr | head -10
du: cannot access '/proc/1583/task/1583/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1583/task/1583/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1583/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1583/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
8636    /
4818    /usr
3779    /usr/src
2188    /var
1052    /snap
1010    /var/lib
791 /var/log
785 /var/log/journal/3aa92fc7b26a4f78b870ea2dd0a76525
785 /var/log/journal
582 /snap/core
```

Comment: Could you try posting the result of `df –h /dev/nvme0n1p1` please?

Comment: @darth_epoxy Hi, I just edit the post please check it for the new edit. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the system is consistently running out of space, check that it’s not your log files in `/var/log` that are causing the shortage. If you’re using Apache or nginx, check that those logs are also being properly cleaned up.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, I ran `df -h /var/log` and `got Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  7.5G  232M  98% /`. So is that mean it was from the log that causing the shortage? and if so, how do I clean it? Thank you.

Comment: To check the size of a directory, you'll want to use `du` ⇢ `sudo du -hs /var/log` 

Comment: Hi, just did it and got `791M /var/log` return.

Comment: Well, the next thing to do would be to `du` every directory and find out where all of your storage is being used. You can query the whole system like this: `sudo du -m / | sort -nr | head -10` ⇢ **Note:** *this query will take a long time to run, depending on how many files and directories you have on your system. Do not be surprised if it takes 5 minutes.*

Comment: Thanks. I just did and update the post with the result. So it looks like the `path / and /usr` is taking the most of the space? It is not an actual file so I don't know how to remove it or if it is safe to remove anything. I did `sudo find / -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \;` but got `-r-------- 1 root root 128T Nov 23 17:45 /proc/kcore
find: ‘/proc/1616/task/1616/fdinfo/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/1616/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory`. Pretty sure I'm not doing it correctly lol.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was logs, but not in /var/logs. They were underneath the root where my docker container was deployed, mounted as volumes.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Workspace (Linux) user--I fixed this error in my Pycharm IDE by emptying my trash can (lol)